# Windows forms checkbox text wont do multiline

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make checkbox with text multiline but still without success.
In given code I am trying to make it work for one or at least two lines.

Try N.1

```
var newCheckBox = new Common.Controls.WinForms.Core.CheckBox()
{
    AutoSize = false,
    Location = XXX,
    Name = XXX,
    Text = XXX,
    Checked = XXX,
    AutoEllipsis = false,
};

newCheckBox.ScalingDetails.NormalizedFontSize = XXX;
newCheckBox.Font = XXX;
newCheckBox.ScalingDetails.ScalingFactor = XXX;
newCheckBox.MaximumSize = new Size(200, (newCheckBox.Height) * 2);
Controls.Add(newCheckBox);
```

Result is that only checkbox is visible but no text.

Try N2 - Just changed `AutoSize` to `true` but then text is just cutted in the middle.

How can I make text to be in more lines when its needed?

Comment: You must set the `MinimumSize`, not the `MaximumSize`. The checkBox cannot be smaller than the minimum size.

Comment: This does not seem to be a standard CheckBox nor do i see why its tagged wpf.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes But I want checkbox to have only height that it really needs. So for example when it needs one line just height for one line. When it needs two line just height for two lines. For example I tried to do it for one or two lines only just as trying.

Comment: Unless when placed on a FlowLayoutControl or similar, the following controls will not move up or down when this checkBox changes its height in winforms (this does not look like WPF).

Comment: If your question is about Winforms please edit your post to use `System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox` and I (or someone else) will be able to give you an answer. As it stands, any answer would be a guess because `Common.Controls.WinForms.Core.CheckBox` is not a known class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multi-line `System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox` by using new line character in the `Text string` (`\n`)

Example :

[image: Sample Code Image]

Output -

[image: Sample Output Image]

I hope it'll work for you!

Comment: The question, as it reads today, is not about `System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox`.